# QGIS measure tool window has disappeared?

Tags: qgis, measurements

I'm using QGIS 2.18.14. I'm able to measure with the tool, but there is no dialog box/window with the actual results.

Where is it hiding?

Comment: what operating system are you using (and if linux, which window manager?) Are you using a multiple monitor setup?

Comment: My OS is Windows 10 (with the Fall update). I do have a multiple monitor setup (laptop with 2 monitors) and the dialog box is not hidden on one of these screens.

Comment: Try changing the measurement type, eg from line to area. The dialog box should snap back to its original location (hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

When I do a right-click on the toolbar and check/uncheck the Attributes layer, it is working
[image]

Comment: Attributes toolbar is checked.